# SQLAlchemy in combination with flask --> OperationalError: sqlite no such table

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

Hello I am trying to create a sign up page.
I am using flask and SQLAlchemy.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

#----------------------------------------
#Setup Flask and SQLAlchemy Database

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///users.sqlite3'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class users(db.Model):
    _id = db.Column("íd", db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    passwort = db.Column(db.String(100))

    def __init__(self, name, passwort):
        self.name = name
        self.passwort = passwort

#----------------------------------------
#Flask routes
@app.route("/signup", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['passwort'] == request.form['passwort1']:
            nm = request.form['name']
            pswrt = request.form['passwort']
            user = users(nm, pswrt)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()

    return render_template("signup.html")

#----------------------------------------
#run
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>
        {% block title %}{% endblock %}
    </title>
</head>
<body>

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

signup.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <form action = "{{ request.path }}" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"/><br>
        <input type="text" name="passwort" placeholder="Passwort"><br>
        <input type="text" name="passwort1" placeholder="Passwort wiederholen"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    <a href="{{ url_for('signup') }}">Sign Up</a>
{% endblock %}
```

After running the script and filling some data into the brackets it occures there is no table. In the folder instance there is a users.sqlite3 file, but this is only a text file.

How do i fix this? and what am I doing wrong?

PS: I know the code is not done jet.